# Moving Average Crossover Histogram

Tags: javascript, stock

working on my first javascript indicator for Tradovate. So far everything seems to work great without any bugs. That said, I'd like to make two changes:

- Histogram to plot > 0 (green) *only* if period1Avg is greater than the *HIGH* of period2Avg.
- Histogram to plot < 0 (green) *only* if period1Avg is less than the *LOW* of period2Avg.

This would inherently mean that some sections of the histogram would not plot (i.e. value of 0).

Any assistance on how to edit the script to reflect these changes would be much appreciated!

```
const predef = require("./tools/predef");
const meta = require("./tools/meta");
const SMA = require("./tools/SMA");
const EMA = require("./tools/EMA");
const WMA = require("./tools/WMA");

class TEMP {
    init() {
        switch(this.props.period1type) {
          case "Simple":
              this.period1Avg = SMA(this.props.period1);
              break;
          case "Exponential":
              this.period1Avg = EMA(this.props.period1);
              break;
          case "Weighted":
              this.period1Avg = WMA(this.props.period1);
              break;        
          default:
              this.period1Avg = SMA(this.props.period1);          
        }
        switch(this.props.period2type) {
          case "Simple":
              this.period2Avg = SMA(this.props.period2);
              break;
          case "Exponential":
              this.period2Avg = EMA(this.props.period2);
              break;
          case "Weighted":
              this.period2Avg = WMA(this.props.period2);
              break;        
          default:
              this.period2Avg = SMA(this.props.period2);          
        }
    }

    map(d) {
        const value = d.value();
        const diff = this.period1Avg(value) - this.period2Avg(value);
        const plotColor = { color: diff > 0 ? "green" : "red" };
        return {
            value: diff,
            style: { value: plotColor }
        };
    }
}

module.exports = {
    name: "TEMP",
    description: "TEMP",
    calculator: TEMP,
    params: {
        period1: predef.paramSpecs.period(8),
        period1type: predef.paramSpecs.enum({value1: "Simple", value2: "Exponential", value3: "Weighted"}),
        period2: predef.paramSpecs.period(34),
        period2type: predef.paramSpecs.enum({value1: "Simple", value2: "Exponential", value3: "Weighted"})
    },
    tags: [predef.tags.MovingAverage],
    inputType: meta.InputType.BARS,
    areaChoice: meta.AreaChoice.NEW,
    plots: {
        value: { displayOnly: true }
    },
    plotter: predef.plotters.histogram
};
```